# (clarify this answer?) Prove that for all subsets of the reals A, there exists a Borel set $A \subset B$ such that $\lambda(B) = \lambda^*(A) $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

This (or a similar) question has been asked already on stackexchange. I am asking for a variation on the accepted answer.

[Prove for each $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ there exists Borel set whose measure is same as outer measure of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611797/prove-for-each-a-subset-mathbbr-there-exists-borel-set-whose-measure-is-sam?rq=1)

how do we relate this to the question above, where in we must consider $\lambda(B)$ instead of $\lambda^*(B)$?

Comment: Do you mean $\lambda(B)=\lambda^*(A)$?

Comment: I have edited my question admins

Answer (score 1):

If you analize the definition of $\lambda^*(A)$, you get $\lambda^*(A)=\inf \{\sum_n \lambda(E_n) \mbox{ where } (E_n)_{n \in amthbb{N}} \mbox{ is a countable covering of } A   \}$ and thus for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $(E_k^n)_k$ such that $\sum_k \lambda (E_k^n) \leq \lambda^*(A)+\frac 1 n$.
If you take $E=\bigcap_n\bigcup_k E_k^n$ you have that $E$ is what you are searching for. In fact $\lambda^*(A) \leq \lambda(E) \leq \lambda^*(A)+\frac 1 n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Note that this holds in general for every $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ measure space the "borel" set is replaced by $E \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: what is the difference between lambda star and lambda?

Comment: @BIGFATNIH $\lambda^*$ is the external measure, $\lambda$ is the measure.

Comment: please define it?

Comment: @BIGFATNIH definitions like external measure and measure are things you can easily find online.

Comment: @JetChung I know that for sets of disjoint intervals, the outer measure is equal to the inner measure. This makes the outer measure and inner measures of $B_k$ in the answer referenced above equivalent. How can we use that to prove the question?

Comment: @BIGFATNIH I tried to edit the question. Note that the definition of $\lambda^*$ is written above implicitly.

Comment: Are you sure you intended to include the sum symbol?

Comment: @BIGFATNIH Yes I am, that's the definition of $\lambda^*$.